Klocwork unexpected NUM.OVERFLOW.DF warning
My function is shown below. I got NUM.OVERFLOW.DF warning on line Delta = Coord1 - Coord2; and Delta = Coord2 - Coord1; Is it a bug or something wrong in my code?
boolean ValidMoveDelta(uint16 Coord1, uint16 Coord2, uint8 Threshold)
{
    uint16 Delta = 0;
    boolean boResult = FALSE;

    // ensure no negative value
    if (Coord1 > Coord2)
    {
        Delta = Coord1 - Coord2;
    }
    else
    {
        Delta = Coord2 - Coord1;
    }

    if (Delta >= Threshold)
    {
        boResult = TRUE;
    }

    return boResult;
}


Which version of Klocwork are you using?

It is version 23.4

Klocwork checker NUM.OVERFLOW.DF can report the issue if there are possible cases of numeric overflow or wraparound in an arithmetic operation.
When performing subtraction (e.g., Coord1 - Coord2), no negative values are allowed in unsigned arithmetic. If Coord2 is greater than Coord1, the subtraction will result in a wraparound (underflow), leading to unexpected large values. uint16 is an unsigned 16-bit integer with a range of 0 to 65535.
in this case i believe the Static code analysis tool you are using (Klocwork) has reported a valid issue.
To resolve this, you may consider to cast the uint16 variables to a signed type (e.g., int32) during the subtraction to ensure that underflow doesn't occur, then convert back if necessary.

i agree with your statement but i have added the condition to check which one has a greater value. So wraparound is not possible
